# How to average data from Sentinel-5p collection ignoring zero?

Tags: google-earth-engine, conditional, data-collection, average, sentinel-5p

I am working with CH4 product Sentinel-5p provided by ESA Copernicus.

Remote User Support provided a script to extract averaged CH4 anomalies for a certain period for the Earth Engine.
However, I suspect, that the results provide averaged values that include a 'zero value', because they use `collection.mean()`.

Usually, I use conditional operator '@ ? @ : @' in ESA SNAP environment. Thus, I tried to implement this function to the RUS script but it didn't work.

Please, give me a suggestion, how to average the data ignoring zero from the image collection in the Earth Engine environment

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4')
  .select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air')
  .filterDate('2020-04-06', '2020-04-10');
```

Here I put `expression('condition ? true_action : false_action)` instead of the `collection.mean()`

```
var s5p_L3_CH4_APR = collection.expression(('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air' != 0) ? 1 : 0).clip(geometry)
var band_viz = {
  min: 1750,
  max: 1900,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(s5p_L3_CH4_APR, band_viz, 'S5P CH4');
Map.setCenter(24.436, 49.481, 2);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: s5p_L3_CH4_APR,
  description: 's5p_L3_CH4_2020APR',
  scale: 7500,
  region: geometry
})
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

```js
.expression(('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air' != 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

First, you have not written an Earth Engine expression but a *JavaScript* expression, because the expression is *outside of the quotes*. You must quote the entire expression so that it will be passed to the Earth Engine server.

```js
.expression('(CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air != 0) ? 1 : 0')
```

Second, you can't refer to a band by writing its name: you need to either use the `b()` syntax or pass it as an explicitly defined variable. The first is simpler here, so let's  do that:

```js
.expression('(b("CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air") != 0) ? 1 : 0')
```

(Note that the inner quotes must be different from the outer quotes — it doesn't matter whether they're single or double but the can't be the same. Alternatively, you could write `b[0]` to request the first band regardless of its name, which will work here since you already `.select()`ed the band you're looking for.)

Third, you can't apply an image expression to an image *collection;* you must map over the collection to apply the image expression to each element.

```js
var s5p_L3_CH4_APR = collection.map(function (image) {
  return image
    .clip(geometry)
    .expression('(b("CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air") != 0) ? 1 : 0');
});
```

This is enough to get your script to *run*. However, it won't actually get the results you want — they will all be zero, because you've just *replaced* the data with your comparison, but it sounds like you want to *mask* the data:

```js
var s5p_L3_CH4_APR = collection.map(function (image) {
  return image
    .clip(geometry)
    .updateMask(image.expression('b("CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air") != 0'));
});
```

Notice I have also removed the `? 1 : 0`. This is not because it is wrong, but because it is unnecessary: Earth Engine's boolean operators on images *already* return 1 for true and 0 for false.

Now we can see the data. One more thing: you haven't requested a mean of this filtered data, so the layer is using most-recent-on-top mosaicing and the export will fail.

```js
var s5p_L3_CH4_APR =
  collection.map(function (image) {
    return image
      .clip(geometry)
      .updateMask(image.expression('b("CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air") != 0'));
  })
  .mean();
```

This should compute what you asked for.